# Have age_calc() from eeptools handle NAs sanely

Tags: r

I am trying to use age_calc() from eeptools to calculate age from the date of birth in the dataframe, df.

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(5127, 7670, 10592, 9879, 6097, 
7947, NA, 4520, 10075, 9314), class = "Date"), var = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", "var"), 
row.names = 1:10, class = "data.frame")

#          date var
# 1  1984-01-15   1
# 2  1991-01-01   1
# 3  1999-01-01   1
# 4  1997-01-18   1
# 5  1986-09-11   1
# 6  1991-10-05   0
# 7        <NA>   0
# 8  1982-05-18   1
# 9  1997-08-02   2
# 10 1995-07-03   1
```

I run this line of code to calculate the age in years from today.

```
ages <- age_calc(df$date, units = "years")
```

However, it throws this error because of the NA.

```
Error in if (any(enddate < dob)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is there any way to make age_calc() handle NAs better? For example, just ignore them and output an NA. I did a work-around but it was hackish and ugly. I ended up changing all the NAs to 1000-01-01 calculating the ages then replacing them with NAs again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `na.omit` to drop the `NA`

```
ages <- age_calc(na.omit(df$date), units = "years")
df$ages[!is.na(df$date)] <- ages

         date var     ages
1  1984-01-15   1 33.44932
2  1991-01-01   1 26.48767
3  1999-01-01   1 18.48767
4  1997-01-18   1 20.44110
5  1986-09-11   1 30.79452
6  1991-10-05   0 25.72877
7        <NA>   0       NA
8  1982-05-18   1 35.11233
9  1997-08-02   2 19.90411
10 1995-07-03   1 21.98630
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a much nicer way to do it.