# Handling missing data with age_calc in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `age_calc` from the `eeptools` R package on a dataset where both my dob and enddate vectors contain missing data. I'm trying to implement the workaround suggested in the answer to the following post: [Have age_calc() from eeptools handle NAs sanely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812301/have-age-calc-from-eeptools-handle-nas-sanely)

However I'm struggling to get the code to work when specifying both the dob and the enddate. The following is what I'm trying to make work:

```
age <- age_calc(dob=(na.omit(df$date1)),
                enddate=(na.omit(df$date2)),
                units="years",
                precise=TRUE)

df$age [!is.na(df$date1) & !is.na(df$date2)] <- age
```

At the moment I'm getting stuck on the first stage, with the error message:

```
Error in age_calc(dob=(na.omit(df$date1)),  :
  End date must be a date after date of birth
```

I've double checked that all the dates in df$date2 do come after df$date1, so I think I must have coded `na.omit` in a way that the function doesn't understand which date is which (?)

I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious - any advice much appreciated.

Alice

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
na_free_df <- df[complete.cases(df),]

age <- age_calc(dob = na_free_df$date1,
                enddate = na_free_df$date2,
                units = "years",
                precise = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I gave that a try, but got the following error message: `Error in mapply(seq, as.POSIXct(start), as.POSIXct(end), by = "years", : zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length`. I'm not sure what this means - any thoughts?

Comment: One of the vectors you’re inputting into the function might not exist. Is dput(df) on your data.frame and c+p output from console into your question